# Keyboard slow response

Tags: keyboard

In all applications (Notepad++, Visual Studio, etc) from time to time the keyboard keys I press are a bit delayed before actually being handled by the operating system.

This is for every key on the keyboard. Arrows, Start button, Characters etc.

I have tried the following things:

- Used another USB port
- Checked for malware (Key loggers etc)
- Checked for processes with high CPU usage (none)
- Checked for available memory (About 1000MB)

I can't think of any other causes for this problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you able to try a different keyboard? It would help to know if it's just that keyboard or a broader issue.

Comment: Good comment. I am using a Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000, and I have used a Logitec OEM keyboard with the same problems.

Comment: This is a very strange behaviour. Have you tried to reinstall the default keyboard driver provided by your system (I know that sounds weird but it might help)? Do you have any other USB devices attached?

Comment: @MichaelK Good tip. I will try that and post my findings.

Comment: As you've changed keyboard my suggestion would be to check your system's RAM and CPU usage. Slow keyboard commands can be a symptom of a struggling system - either overloaded with software/running processes or a below par/older processor being pushed to its limits.

Comment: @HaydnWVN Good suggestion. It appears to be there is a difference between `Available` and `Free` memory.  In my case there was about 10 MB free memory, and another GB in standby. The other memory (about 5GB) was consumed by Visual studio and SQL server instances.  I will now figure out what the different kind of free memory numbers mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appeared to be my memory usage. I was out of free memory and my machine started to swap a lot.

Apparently my new installation of ReSharper increased Visual Studio memory usage bij 300mb per instance (of which I usually have 5 open).